Create spatial weighting matrix by Stata
I used -spmatrix create command to create weighting matrix but when I created idistance, no matter I change the vtruncate(1/180) or vtruncate(1/350) the output matrix result is the same. how to fix that?
Command I used:
spmatrix create idistance W180 if year==2021, vtruncate(1/180) norm(row)replace

spmatrix create idistance W350 if year==2021, vtruncate(1/350) norm(row)replace

Please help me to solve that problem

Cross-posted https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1769643-spatial-weighting-matrix-for-panel-data
